# Underscore.js groupBy multiple values

Tags: arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects

Using Underscore.js, I'm trying to group a list of items multiple times, ie

Group by SIZE then for each SIZE, group by CATEGORY...

http://jsfiddle.net/rickysullivan/WTtXP/1/

Ideally, I'd like to have a function or extend [`_.groupBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) so that you can throw an array at it with the paramaters to group by.

```js
var multiGroup = ['size', 'category'];
```

Probably could just make a mixin...

```js
_.mixin({
    groupByMulti: function(obj, val, arr) {
        var result = {};
        var iterator = typeof val == 'function' ? val : function(obj) {
                return obj[val];
            };
        _.each(arr, function(arrvalue, arrIndex) {
            _.each(obj, function(value, objIndex) {
                var key = iterator(value, objIndex);
                var arrresults = obj[objIndex][arrvalue];
                if (_.has(value, arrvalue))
                    (result[arrIndex] || (result[arrIndex] = [])).push(value);
```

My head hurts, but I think some more pushing needs to go here...

```js
            });
        })
        return result;
    }
});

properties = _.groupByMulti(properties, function(item) {

    var testVal = item["size"];

    if (parseFloat(testVal)) {
        testVal = parseFloat(item["size"])
    }

    return testVal

}, multiGroup);
```

Comment: an example of input and desired output would probably help...

Comment: Input is in the fiddle at the top, output like this...http://jsfiddle.net/rickysullivan/G9sd6/

Comment: Actually, this rev...http://jsfiddle.net/rickysullivan/G9sd6/1/

Comment: What is `val` supposed to do? You said you'd pass an array of strings (or of functions, I don't mind)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A simple recursive implementation:

```js
_.mixin({
  /*
   * @mixin
   *
   * Splits a collection into sets, grouped by the result of running each value
   * through iteratee. If iteratee is a string instead of a function, groups by
   * the property named by iteratee on each of the values.
   *
   * @param {array|object} list - The collection to iterate over.
   * @param {(string|function)[]} values - The iteratees to transform keys.
   * @param {object=} context - The values are bound to the context object.
   * 
   * @returns {Object} - Returns the composed aggregate object.
   */
  groupByMulti: function(list, values, context) {
    if (!values.length) {
      return list;
    }
    var byFirst = _.groupBy(list, values[0], context),
        rest    = values.slice(1);
    for (var prop in byFirst) {
      byFirst[prop] = _.groupByMulti(byFirst[prop], rest, context);
    }
    return byFirst;
  }
});
```

[Demo in your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTtXP/25/)

Answer (score 17):

I think @Bergi's answer can be streamlined a bit by utilizing Lo-Dash's `mapValues`  (for mapping functions over object values). It allows us to group the entries in an array by multiple keys in a nested fashion:

```
_ = require('lodash');

var _.nest = function (collection, keys) {
  if (!keys.length) {
    return collection;
  }
  else {
    return _(collection).groupBy(keys[0]).mapValues(function(values) { 
      return nest(values, keys.slice(1));
    }).value();
  }
};
```

I renamed the method to `nest` because it ends up serving much the same role served by D3's [nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) operator. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/9834587) for details and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7an5/2/) for demonstrated usage with your example.

[lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) [nest](/questions/tagged/nest) [groupby](/questions/tagged/groupby)

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer.

Answer (score 16):

How about this rather simple hack?

```
console.log(_.groupBy(getProperties(), function(record){
    return (record.size+record.category);
}));
```

Comment: It is better to add something between two fields, like: record.size + "`"+record.category (any unusual symbol or char(0)) to prevent cases, where you have pairs: "12"+"3" and "1"+"23"

Comment: For me this is the epic response.Just make sure you return it as string as @agershun states

Answer (score 1):

Check out this underscore extension: [Underscore.Nest](https://github.com/iros/underscore.nest), by Irene Ros.

This extension's output will be slightly different from what you specify, but the module is only about 100 lines of code, so you should be able to scan to get direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for the *reduce* phase of *map-reduce*. It's not going to be as visually elegant as the multi-group function (you can't just pass in an array of keys to group on), but overall this pattern gives you more flexibility to transform your data. [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tynman/djQnD/1/)

```
var grouped = _.reduce(
    properties, 
    function(buckets, property) {
        // Find the correct bucket for the property
        var bucket = _.findWhere(buckets, {size: property.size, category: property.category});

        // Create a new bucket if needed.
        if (!bucket) {
            bucket = {
                size: property.size, 
                category: property.category, 
                items: []
            };
            buckets.push(bucket);
        }

        // Add the property to the correct bucket
        bucket.items.push(property);
        return buckets;
    }, 
    [] // The starting buckets
);

console.log(grouped)
```

But if you just want it in an underscore mixin, here's my stab at it:

```
_.mixin({
'groupAndSort': function (items, sortList) {
    var grouped = _.reduce(
        items,
        function (buckets, item) {
            var searchCriteria = {};
            _.each(sortList, function (searchProperty) { searchCriteria[searchProperty] = item[searchProperty]; });
            var bucket = _.findWhere(buckets, searchCriteria);

            if (!bucket) {
                bucket = {};
                _.each(sortList, function (property) { bucket[property] = item[property]; });
                bucket._items = [];
                buckets.push(bucket);
            }

            bucket._items.push(item);
            return buckets;
        },
        [] // Initial buckets
    );

    grouped.sort(function (x, y) {
        for (var i in sortList) {
            var property = sortList[i];
            if (x[property] != y[property])
                return x[property] > y[property] ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    return _.map(grouped, function (group) {
        var toReturn = { key: {}, value: group.__items };
        _.each(sortList, function (searchProperty) { toReturn.key[searchProperty] = group[searchProperty]; });
        return toReturn;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The improvements by joyrexus on bergi's method don't take advantage of the underscore/lodash mixin system. Here it is as a mixin:

```
_.mixin({
  nest: function (collection, keys) {
    if (!keys.length) {
      return collection;
    } else {
      return _(collection).groupBy(keys[0]).mapValues(function(values) {
        return _.nest(values, keys.slice(1));
      }).value();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with lodash and mixin

```
_.mixin({
'groupByMulti': function (collection, keys) {
if (!keys.length) {
 return collection;
 } else {
  return _.mapValues(_.groupBy(collection,_.first(keys)),function(values) {
    return _.groupByMulti(values, _.rest(keys));
  });
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to understand function.

```
function mixin(list, properties){

    function grouper(i, list){

        if(i < properties.length){
            var group = _.groupBy(list, function(item){
                var value = item[properties[i]];
                delete item[properties[i]];
                return value;
            });

            _.keys(group).forEach(function(key){
                group[key] = grouper(i+1, group[key]);
            });
            return group;
        }else{
            return list;
        }
    }

    return grouper(0, list);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by a composite key tends to work better for me in most situations:

```
const groups = _.groupByComposite(myList, ['size', 'category']);
```

[Demo using OP's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve91w4jv/6/)

### Mixin

```
_.mixin({
  /*
   * @groupByComposite
   *
   * Groups an array of objects by multiple properties. Uses _.groupBy under the covers,
   * to group by a composite key, generated from the list of provided keys.
   *
   * @param {Object[]} collection - the array of objects.
   * @param {string[]} keys - one or more property names to group by.
   * @param {string} [delimiter=-] - a delimiter used in the creation of the composite key.
   *
   * @returns {Object} - the composed aggregate object.
   */
  groupByComposite: (collection, keys, delimiter = '-') =>
    _.groupBy(collection, (item) => {
      const compositeKey = [];
      _.each(keys, key => compositeKey.push(item[key]));
      return compositeKey.join(delimiter);
    }),
});
```