# Underscore.js: transform an array of objects into a multi-level nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, underscore.js, transformation

How would you do this kind of transformation in a functional way with underscore.js?  I've repeated the following pattern several times lately, and it seems kind of ugly to me.

```
var fruitList = [
        { id:1, name:lime, color:green, size:small },
        { id:2, name:banana, color:yellow, size:large },
        { id:3, name:lemon, color:yellow, size:small },
        { id:4, name:papaya, color:green, size:large },
        { id:5, name:kiwi, color:green, size:small },
        { id:6, name:apple, color:green, size:small },
        { id:7, name:pear, color:yellow, size:small },
        { id:8, name:grape, color:green, size:small },
        { id:9, name:mango, color:yellow, size:large },
        { id:10, name:honeydew, color:green, size:large }
    ],
    fruitByColorThenSize = {};

jQuery.each(fruitList, function (fruit) {
    if (!fruitByColorThenSize[fruit.color]) {
        fruitByColorThenSize[fruit.color] = {};
    }

    if (!fruitByColorThenSize[fruit.color][fruit.size]) {
        fruitByColorThenSize[fruit.color][fruit.size] = {};
    }

    fruitByColorThenSize[fruit.color][fruit.size][fruit.id] = fruit.name;
});
```

fruitByColorThenSize would then look similar to this:

```
{
    yellow: {
        large: {
            2: 'banana',
            9: 'mango'
        },
        small: {
            3: 'lemon',
            7: 'pear'
        }
    },
    green: {
        large: {
            4: 'papaya',
            10: 'honeydew'
        },
        small: {
            1: 'lime',
            5: 'kiwi',
            6: 'apple',
            8: 'grape'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice function called [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) which does exactly what you want, yet for a one-dimensional object only. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869056/1048572) I've written a generic multidimensional version of it, but for your case the following <s>functional</s> script is enough:

```
var fruitList = […];

var fruitByColorThenSize = _.groupBy(fruitList, "color");
for (var color in fruitByColorThenSize) {
    var byColor = _.groupBy(fruitByColorThenSize[color], "size");
    for (var size in byColor) {
        var bySize = _.groupBy(byColor[size], "id");
        for (var id in bySize) {
            bySize[id] = bySize[0].name;
        }
        byColor[size] = bySize;
    }
    fruitByColorThenSize[color] = byColor;
}
```

> I've repeated the following pattern several times lately

Then write a generic function abstracting over it! It's quite simple:

```
function getBy(arr, valprop, props) {
    var res = {};
    $.each(arr, function(obj) {
        var acc = res;
        for (var i=0; i<props.length; i++) {
            var prop = obj[props[i]];
            if (i==props.length-1) 
                acc[prop] = obj[valprop];
            else {
                if (! (prop in acc))
                    acc[prop] = {};
                acc = acc[prop];
            }
        }
    });
    return res;
}
// usage:
var fruitByColorThenSize = getBy(fruitList, "name", ["color", "size", "id"]);
```

Comment: I'm getting an array [using your solution](http://jsbin.com/otiquw/2/edit), instead of an object.

Comment: Yes, this gets part of the way there.  @Bergi's code generates an array of arrays of objects, while I was looking for an object of objects of objects.  I will check out the linked multidimensional answer more closely tomorrow.  Also, the link there to underscore.nest looks cool.  Thanks!

Comment: @idbehold: Oops, I though Underscore's map on objects would return an object. That will make the answer less functional :-(