# How to assign value in $scope inside ng-repeat angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem now regarding the ng-repeat in angularJS on how to assign value in $scope inside ng-repeat..

This is my scenorio:

I have a json file that content all the data. It shows like this..

```
[
{BookID:1,Chapter:1,ContentID:1,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:1,ContentID:2,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:1,ContentID:3,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:1,ContentID:4,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:2,ContentID:1,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:2,ContentID:2,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:2,ContentID:3,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:1,Chapter:2,ContentID:4,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:2,Chapter:1,ContentID:1,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:2,Chapter:1,ContentID:2,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:2,Chapter:1,ContentID:3,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"},
{BookID:2,Chapter:1,ContentID:4,Content:"The quick brown fox is nice"}
]
```

Now that is my Example data..

When Book 1 is click, I want to Display it like this..

```
Book 1

Chapter 1
1 The quick brown fox is nice. 2 The quick brown fox is nice. 3 The quick brown fox is nice. 4 The quick brown fox is nice

Chapter 2
1 The quick brown fox is nice. 2 The quick brown fox is nice. 3 The quick brown fox is nice. 4 The quick brown fox is nice
```

This is my Code:

```
//Chapter is expected in every book so i just loop it depending on expected chapters (e.i, 1,2,3,4

<div data-ng-repeat="chap in Chapters">
        <span style="font-size:20px">{{chap}}</span>
        <span data-ng-repeat="testament in Testaments | filter:filters">
            <b>{{testament.ContentID}}</b> {{testament.Content}}
        </span>
        <br />
    </div>
```

In my Controller :

```
$scope.filters = function (row) {
        var bookId = row.BookID.toString();
        var chapter = row.Chapter.toString();
        return ( bookId == $scope.bookId && chapter == $scope.currentChapter);
    };
```

Now the Problem is that where i can get the `$scope.currentChapter` which must the value of `chap`

Please help me how assign value to `$scope.currentChapter` from the `chap`

Thank you so much..

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong angle. Transform your data into something sensible/hierarchical, then the view binding will be simple.

Comment: yes i also know about that but the data came from other people..and its a lot to work for so i need to find a solution to use that..

Comment: i know it is simple if i array the `content` inside the `chapter` and array the `chapter` inside a `book`..

Comment: It looks like a pretty data transformation to me. Using an [underscore mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869056/1860652) it's just `_(books).groupByMultiple(['BookID', 'Chapter', 'ContentID'])`

Comment: oh pretty cool huh..that's nice..thanks for that new information for me..thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom fiter and pass 'chap' as a parameter. Or u can write:

```
    <span data-ng-repeat="testament in Testaments | filter:{'BookID':bookId}:true | filter:{Chapter:chap}:true">
        <b>{{testament.ContentID}}</b> {{testament.Content}}
    </span>
```

Two filters here for bookId and chapter, :true means 'exact match'.

Comment: Thanks pal..this is awesome... almost a day i've searching for this but now i got it..this is absolute what i need..

Comment: And thanks for the info about `:true` now i know..thanks a lot