# Group objects by multiple values and combining duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of data that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "20200722_3",
      "eventDate": "2020-07-22T00:00:00",
      "eventName": "Football",
      "eventDetails": [
        "Men's First Round (2 matches)"
      ],
      "eventVenue": "Venue A"
    },
    {
      "id": "20200722_1",
      "eventDate": "2020-07-22T00:00:00",
      "eventName": "Football",
      "eventDetails": [
        "Men's First Round (2 matches)"
      ],
      "eventVenue": "Venue B"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I wanted to group the data by multiple properties. For example, by `eventDate`, `eventName`, `eventDetails`, and `eventVenue`. Which I've done with this code referenced from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47342275/5027965):

```
const groupBy = (array, attrs) => {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var ele = array[i];
    var groups = output;
    for (var j = 0; j < attrs.length; ++j) {
      var attr = attrs[j];
      var value = ele[attr];
      var gs = groups.filter(g => {
        return g.hasOwnProperty('label') && g['label'] === value;
      });
      if (gs.length === 0) {
        var g = {};
          if (isArray.g['label'] ) {

          }
        g['label'] = value;
        g['groups'] = [];
        groups.push(g);
        groups = g['groups'];
      } else {
        groups = gs[0]['groups'];
      }
    }
    groups.push(ele);
  }
  return output;
}

var result = groupBy(data, ['eventDate', 'eventName', 'eventDetails', 'eventVenue'])
```

Which results in an array like this:

```
[{
    "label": "2020-07-23T00:00:00",
    "groups": [{
        "label": "Football",
        "groups": [{
            "label": [
              "Men's First Round (2 matches)"
            ],
            "groups": [{
              "label": "Venue A",
              "groups": [
                "Object"
              ]
            }]
          },
          {
            "label": [
              "Men's First Round (2 matches)"
            ],
            "groups": [{
              "label": "Venue B",
              "groups": [
                "Object"
              ]
            }]
          }
        }]
    }]
}]
```

You can see that for the output above, there are two separate "groups" that have the label `"Men's First Round (2 matches)"`. I'm trying to figure out how I can combine these objects that have duplicate value ? I'm looking for something that would output like this:

```
[{
    "label": "2020-07-23T00:00:00",
    "groups": [{
        "label": "Football",
        "groups": [{
            "label": [
              "Men's First Round (2 matches)"
            ],
            "groups": [{
              "label": "Venue A",
              "groups": [
                "Object"
              ]
            },
            {
              "label": "Venue B",
              "groups": [
                "Object"
              ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share the answer that I came up with for those that are curious.
For my needs, I know that if the array with the `eventName` only contained 1 attribute, it could be a duplicate. So in order to fix that, I converted the array that only had 1 value to a string:

```
if (ele[attr] && ele[attr].length === 1) {
  var value = ele[attr].toString();
} else {
  var value = ele[attr];
}
```