# Groupby array by multiple values

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an array I want to use groupby angular's filter and to group it by an array of criterias. Is there any way to do this? I guess I might use revision but I don't know how.

For example I have array of football teams. Each team have color, number of players, name, city, country.
I have array of data filters -country, city, players and color and I want to use groupby in the order of this array

Answer (score 0):

not sure about angular. but just include underscore (it's more known for array/object manipulation) into your project then:

say you had an array of objects like an array of these:

```
car = {
    make: "nissan",
    model: "sunny",
    color: "red"
};
```

then you'd just go:

```
var redCars = _.groupBy(cars, 'color');
```

Comment: But if I have an array of groupby values I want to use? This is my problem. Let's say I want to groupby color and then by brand and then by year

Comment: not sure what you mean, show an example of your array in your original question

Comment: you might want to look at multiple group by with underscore then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022156/underscore-js-groupby-multiple-values